# I can't flip my pose for my animation?

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes, pose-mode

So I am currently following a [mech tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qDnZroK28c&t=600s) on animating a run cycle. At about 7:27 in the video (after he posed/key framed the mech in the first frame), the guy copied the key frames in the first frame and pasted/flipped them (ctrl+shift+v) on frame 10. The pose was perfectly flipped for him.

On the other hand, when I tried to do it, my mech became distorted. Here is the first frame of my mech's run cycle.

[image]

And here's how my mech looks in frame 10 when I paste/flipped the pose in frame 10.

[image]

As you can see, the body becomes distorted and weird. I did some research and I tried to rename the control bones on my feet to indicate which ones are left and right, but that didn't work.

I tried to recalculate my roll (shift+N) for all my bones for the Global +Z Axis in edit mode, but that didn't work either. 
I should note that when I did recalculate my roll, the z axis for most of my bones did recalculate properly, except for a few. Including the pole bones for my feet.

Here's a photo before of all of my bone's axises before I recalculated their rolls.

[image]

And here's the after image.

[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong??? How do I flip my pose correctly?
Here's a copy of my [Blender file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah2aL3r7RO3ThPESeXh36JFggJp4mg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is a mix of wrong names and bad orientations.

You say that you tried to rename your bones, but in your file they are not properly renamed. The left foot must be named something like *foot_L*, and right foot something like *foot_R*, otherwise when you'll flip the pose, Blender won't be able to understand to what bone it is supposed to paste.

So when you have finished a side of your armature you should properly name all your bones, then, in *Edit* mode, select them all and *Armature* > *Symmetrize* so that it copy paste on the other side.

Also, you'll probably need to correct the rotation of the lower leg due to the IK: Once in *Pose* mode, select the lower leg, go into the *Properties* panel > *Bone Constraints*, play with *Pole Angle* value to correct the orientation.

[image]

Comment: My bad. Looks like I just named the pole bones. Thought I renamed them and the foot control bones.
 So I renamed the two control bones (along with every bone in the rig) and it helped a little, but the feet are still a bit distorted. Also I tried ctrl+R (in pose mode) and shift+N (in edit mode). Ctrl+R didn't seem to do much of anything and shift+N seemed to distort the legs even more.

Comment: here is a copy of my most recent save [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah2aL3r7RO3ThPF6MVgTLmJqpXzx5w). Note on this copy I ctrl+z the shift+n that I performed earlier.

Comment: So what you need to do is delete all the right bones in Edit mode, symmetrize the left bones (select all, then Armature menu > Symmetrize), in Pose mode correct the lower_leg.R pole angle to 180° (in the IK constraint panel of the bone), then it works fine. Also put the root in the middle.

Comment: @SMH It will definitely be worth it to put some time into naming your bones properly. Otherwise you can easily get confused or slow when animating or checking the graph editor.

Comment: @moonboots thank you for saving my ass again